# Destroying instantiated objects in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, destroy, gameobject

I want to delete an instantiated gameobject in Unity. I am using a for loop in instantiating a dynamic buttons and I want to destroy it before using it again because number of buttons is just appending and not over writing. This is my code in instantiating:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {

        goButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabButton);
        goButton.transform.SetParent(panel, false);
        goButton.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        //print name in Button
        goButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = names[i];

        //get Url from firebase
        string Url = url[i]; 
        WWW www = new WWW (Url);
        yield return www;
        Texture2D texture = www.texture;

        //load image in button
        Image img = goButton.GetComponent<Image>();
        img.sprite = Sprite.Create (texture, new Rect (0, 0, texture.width, texture.height),Vector2.zero);

        Button tempButton = goButton.GetComponent<Button>();

        int tempInt = i;

        string name = names [i];

        tempButton.onClick.AddListener (() => hello (tempInt, name));
    }
```

I tried adding Destroy(goButton) before the for loop but only the last button is being destroyed. What could be the possible solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Destroy(goButton)`, it will only destroy the current `GameObject` that variable is referencing (not all the `GameObject`s it used to reference). It seems like the problem you're trying to solve is "How can I destroy *multiple* instantiated objects" and you have two basic options here. One would be to save references to all the `GameObjects` in a C# collection (like a `List<>` or `HashSet<>`).  Your other option would be to use an empty `GameObject` as a "container object", parent everything under that, then destroy the container when you're done with them all.

Creating/Deleting via the first option would look something like this:

```
// Note this class is incomplete but should serve as an example
public class ButtonManager
{
    private List<GameObject> m_allButtons = new List<GameObject>();

    public void CreateButtons()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            GameObject goButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabButton);
            m_allButtons.Add(goButton);
            ...
        } 
    }

    public void DestroyButtons()
    {
        foreach (GameObject button in allButtons)
        {
            Destroy(button);
        }
        allButtons.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuu